# Comparison of first Chern class

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, chern-classes

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface over $\mathbb{C}$, $M, N$ are rank two vector bundles (locally free sheaves of rank two) on $X$. Moreover, $N$ is a subsheaf of $M$.

My first question is why $c_{1}(N)=c_{1}(M)$ imply $N\cong M$, where $c_{1}(N)$ is the first Chern class of $N$.

Let $H$ be an ample divisor of $X$.  Is it true that $c_{1}(N)H\leq c_{1}(M)H$? where $c_{1}(N)H$ is just the intersection of $c_{1}(N)$ and $H$.

My last question is what is the general form for comparison of Chern class? Is there any reference? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If $N$ is a subbundle of $M$ with $\operatorname{rank}M = \operatorname{rank}N$, then $M\cong N$.

Comment: I do not think so. For example, in $\mathbb{P}^{2}$, $\mathcal{O}$ can be realize subbundle of $\mathcal{O}(1)$, but $\mathcal {O}$ is not the same as $\mathcal{O}(1)$

Comment: That is not correct. $\mathcal{O}$ is a subsheaf of $\mathcal{O}(1)$, not a subbundle.

Comment: Oh, you are correct, I need to change a little bit for my question.

Comment: Yes, I think now both questions have a positive answer. Denote the cokernel of $N\hookrightarrow M$ by $T$. This is a torsion sheaf with first Chern class $c_1(T)=c_1(M)-c_1(N)=0$. So it is supported in codimension two, but that means $M$ and $N$ only differ in codimension two. As they are locally free, they must already be isomorphic. For the second question: the injection $N\hookrightarrow M$ induces an injection of determinant line bundles. This gives the desired inequality.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand. By the way, where I can find references about Chern class of torsion sheaf?